# How can i style labels for round inputs when they are in different div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, label

I have a container for multiple photos, and radio inputs with labels. I need to put them in div to style and align with photo container.

```css
#Lux1:checked~.mainPhoto {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#Lux2:checked~.mainPhoto {
  margin-left: -40rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="roomPhotos">
  <div class="roomPhotosSlides">
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux1" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux2" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux3" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux4" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux5" />

    <picture class="roomPhoto mainPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux1.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>
    <picture class="roomPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux2.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>
    <picture class="roomPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux3.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>
    <picture class="roomPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux4.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>
    <picture class="roomPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux5.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>

  </div>
  <div class="sliderManual">
    <label for="Lux1" class="manualButton"></label>
    <label for="Lux2" class="manualButton"></label>
    <label for="Lux3" class="manualButton"></label>
    <label for="Lux4" class="manualButton"></label>
    <label for="Lux5" class="manualButton"></label>
  </div>

  <figure class="leftScroll" id="luxLeft">
    <div class="arrowLeft"></div>
  </figure>
  <figure class="rightScroll" id="luxRight">
    <div class="arrowRight"></div>
  </figure>

</div>
```

I am switching between photos with CSS (depending on input checked), I shift the row of images to the left to the width of one photo;
I also have a function which changes the input checked to the left or right or I can just manually check input to select one of the photos.

**Question is how can I style selected label**. Only the one which is currently active. For some reason I really can't find appropriate selector.

```
.manualButton:checked {
  background: blue;
}
```

doesn't work;

```
.roomPhotosSlides input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

by analogy with one of the other answers I found didn't work too.

```
#Lux1:checked ~ .manualButton {
  background: blue;
}
```

Something like this too.

I think the main problem is that my labels are in different divs. Can you explain me how can I make a working selector for current situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:has()` selector like below.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) you can read more about it.

```css
.roomPhotosSlides:has(#Lux1:checked)~.sliderManual label:nth-child(1) {
  color: blue;
}
.roomPhotosSlides:has(#Lux2:checked)~.sliderManual label:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="roomPhotos">
  <div class="roomPhotosSlides">
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux1" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux2" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux3" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux4" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="Lux5" />
    <picture class="roomPhoto mainPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux1.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>
    <picture class="roomPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux2.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>
    <picture class="roomPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux3.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>
    <picture class="roomPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux4.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>
    <picture class="roomPhoto">
      <img src="Rooms/Lux/Lux5.jpg" alt="Lux" />
    </picture>

  </div>
  <div class="sliderManual">
    <label for="Lux1" class="manualButton">Lux1</label>
    <label for="Lux2" class="manualButton">Lux2</label>
    <label for="Lux3" class="manualButton">Lux3</label>
    <label for="Lux4" class="manualButton">Lux4</label>
    <label for="Lux5" class="manualButton">Lux5</label>
  </div>

  <figure class="leftScroll" id="luxLeft">
    <div class="arrowLeft"></div>
  </figure>
  <figure class="rightScroll" id="luxRight">
    <div class="arrowRight"></div>
  </figure>

</div>
```